# $k$-forms taking values on a line bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a manifold and let us consider an element $\Omega\in\Omega^{k}(M,L)$, namely a $k$-form that takes values on the flat line bundle $L\to M$. I want to know what this really means. Does it mean that for every small enough open set $U\subset M$ I can write $\omega$ as

$\Omega=\omega\otimes e$

where $e$ is any local section of $L$ based in $U$ and $\omega\in \Omega^{k}(M)$? Let $d_{\nabla}$ be the exterior covariant derivative acting on $\Omega^{k}(M,L)$. If $L$ is trivial (but with non-trivial connection $\nabla$) then there is an isomorphism $\Omega^{k}(M,L)\simeq \Omega^{k}(M)$. In this case we have that $d_{\nabla}\Omega = 0 \Leftrightarrow d\omega = 0$?, where $\omega$ is the image of $\Omega$ under this isomorphism?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $k$-forms with values in $L$ are locally $\omega\otimes e$, and since $L$ is at least locally trivial, they're locally just ordinary $k$-forms. The only difference is that we glue local forms together potentially with a twist coming from the transition maps of $L$.

For $L$ trivial, then, $\Omega^k(M,L)$ is not only isomorphic, but *equal* to $\Omega^k(M)$. The definition of smooth $k$-form doesn't use the connection. But an isomorphism such as you're interested in, in general nontrivial, is defined by sending any $d$-flat section to a  $\Delta$-flat one, and extending by fiberwise linearity.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. But then, I don't understand example 31 in

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6256.pdf

where the author considers a $d_{\nabla}$-closed element with values on a trivial line bundle $L=M\times\mathbb{R}$ which however is not $d$-closed. By the way, could you please give a reference where I can find more information about $k$-forms valued on a flat vector bundle and the corresponding cohomology groups?

Comment: The $\nabla$-flat forms need not be the $d$-flat ones, even though you can map the one to the other. As I said, *equality* is also an isomorphism between $(L,\nabla)$-valued and $(L,d)$-valed forms, one which has no reason to preserve flatness. You should prefer to study $k$-forms valued in an arbitrary vector bundle, or better yet in a principal bundle, since the connection doesn't initially have much to do with the forms. It's tough to know which text to recommend without knowing your background. Kobayashi's foundations of diff. geo. has a good and general, but hard, treatment.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, now I understand. I am a graduate student in maths, focusing in differential geometry. My reference book in differential geometry has been "Manifolds and differential geometry" by Jeffrey M. Lee and, due to the things that I have been working on, Compact manifolds with special holonomy, by Dominic Joyce. I always found Kobayashi's books a little bit hard to read, but maybe I should try again. In fact I would appreciate if you could recommend me a serious diff. geom. book to use as general reference for questions about fibre bundles, connections,cohomology,Riemannian geometry...